# Slow electrical circuits

Tags: electrical-distribution

I have a three way light circuit in my hallway that is connected to three ceiling lights. When I switch it on the third light will hesitate before lighting up. Why? Also, I have a different issue with my bathroom ceiling fan. It quit working for a few minutes ( the switch) then it started working again but the first couple of "switch ons" were slow or with a slight hesitation. Now it works fine or instantly again. Is this something that I should worry about? Thanks

Comment: Is the third light a fluorescent? Some do take a moment to start.

Comment: Just to eliminate the easy answer, is one a compact fluorescent bulb, and the other two regular incandescent bulbs?

Comment: Are your hallway ceiling light bulbs CFL, LED, or incandescent? CFL and LED bulbs can have or develop startup delays.

Comment: Yes, all three switches will turn off/on all three lights. (the one comes on a second later ) These are LED bulbs.

Answer (score 2):

If the switches have lost their distinct snap into position feel or if you heard a sparking or sizzling sound when you turned the switch on or off it is highly likely that it is time to replace the switch with a new one.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly all three lights are on the same switches, that is, throw either of the 3-way switches, and two lights come one immediately, one comes on a bit later.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a faulty LED bulb (perhaps a manufacturing defect if the bulb is new). Test the theory by swapping the bulbs in lights 2 and 3. If light 2 now hesitates, you just need to replace the bulb.